# How do values get drawn to the stencil buffer in this example?

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math, stencil-buffer

I have a serious problem understanding how stencil buffering in OpenGL works. I followed the examples of a tutorial and the code works of course, but I really don't get at what points I'm writing to the stencil buffer. To me it seems as I'm setting up the stencil tests, masks and everything, but then I just call `glDrawArrays(...)`
 and write the triangles to the output without applying the stencil buffer at all.
I also don't understand why I clear the buffer using `glClear(GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT)`
 before I even draw the triangles. I would be very thankful if somebody could enlighten me.

```
// Draws the initial cube facing upwards
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36); 

//enable stencil testing
glEnable(GL_STENCIL_TEST);

// Draws the floor between the upward cube and downward cube 
glStencilFunc(GL_ALWAYS, 1, 0xFF); /*sets the test function, mask and ref value*/
glStencilOp(GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP, GL_REPLACE); /*defines what happens on restults*/
glStencilMask(0xFF); /*Mask that is applied on the bits before they are written to the stencil buffer*/
glDepthMask(GL_FALSE);
glClear(GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT); /*Why do I clear the buffer here?!?*/
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 36, 6);

// Draws the downward cube (reflection)
glStencilFunc(GL_EQUAL, 1, 0xFF);
glDepthMask(GL_TRUE);
glStencilMask(0x00);

model = glm::scale(
glm::translate(model, glm::vec3(0, 0, -1)),
glm::vec3(1, 1, -1)
);
glUniformMatrix4fv(uniModel, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(model));

glUniform3f(uniColor, 0.3f, 0.3f, 0.3f);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);
glUniform3f(uniColor, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

glDisable(GL_STENCIL_TEST);
```

Comment: "*Why do I clear the buffer here*" Do you understand what the stencil buffer is? I mean, your question is like asking why you clear the color buffer before rendering stuff.

Comment: From my understanding the stencil buffer is like a mask that I apply on the scene that Im rendering. The buffer contains information that I evaluate/compare to the scene I want to render. Depending of the result and the defined operations every fragment of the scene then will be rendered or not. But in this example it looks as if I would clear the buffer before I apply it. Hence the question where I actually do something with the buffer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The third value passed to glStencilOp (GL_REPLACE) tells OpenGL to set the stencil buffer to the *ref* value previously specified in glStencilFunc whenever both the stencil test and the depth test are passed. In this case: 1.

So then the call to glDrawArrays updates the stencil buffer to 1 everyplace where it draws successfully (i.e., passes both tests).

(And the reason you clear it first, is to get rid of any 1's that happened to be there when you started: you don't want them acting as false positives where you didn't draw triangles).

See https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glStencilOp.xml for details.

Comment: But doesn't the documentation just say that this is the point where we can specify the actions that are to happen when the tests pass/fail?

Comment: Yes. And then when you draw triangles that get drawn (i.e., that pass the tests), then those pixels are updated in the stencil buffer.

Comment: Ohh. So if I call ```glDrawArrays(...)``` while being in between ```glEnable(GL_STENCIL_TEST);```and ```glDisable(GL_STENCIL_TEST);``` its not written to the normal output but automatically to the stencil buffer?

Comment: The stencil test is an "and", not an "or". It doesn't happen instead-of anything; it happens *alongside* the rest of the rendering process.

Comment: @FlorianLeuze If you don't want to write the color buffer (just to the stencil buffer), then you can disable writing of the color components by [`glColorMask`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glColorMask.xhtml).

Answer (score 0):

Okay I think I finally get it. And just to provide the answer to anybody else who might have the same thinking barrier I had here is what was my problem.
In my head I thought I have to write the values somehow to the stencil buffer first and afterwards I will write them to the display. Which is wrong as @NicolBolas kindly stated.

The command `glDrawArrays` (while stencilTesting is active) writes to the display as well as to the stencil buffer. By that for everything following we have the stencil of the in my example floor in the buffer and can use it to evaluate whether or not a pixel will be drawn. By that we can effectively make the second cube be drawn only on the Floor and not outside of it. Due to setting `glStencilMask` to all zero before we draw the cube we make sure it doesn't affect the stencil buffer even though the stencil test is applied on the action. If anybody else stumbles upon this I hope this might help. And if this is complete nonsense, please anybody leave a comment with the mistake in my thinking.